# rosjava build problem on Raspberry Pi - (Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly)

Tags: raspberrypi, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I expect I'm aiming too high here...but I thought I'd try rosjava on my raspberry pi :). After messing around with the setting.gradle file (to include only one thing at a time) I'm still getting the error message:

> Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been stopped, killed or may have crashed)
> 09:36:57.876 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
> 09:36:57.890 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
> 09:36:57.919 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonDisappearedException: Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been stopped, killed or may have crashed)
> 09:36:57.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.handleDaemonDisappearance(DaemonClient.java:186)
> 09:36:57.951 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.monitorBuild(DaemonClient.java:148)
> 09:36:57.966 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:119)
> 09:36:57.982 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DaemonBuildAction.run(DaemonBuildAction.java:49)
> 09:36:58.000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ActionAdapter.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:278)
> 09:36:58.016 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ActionAdapter.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:270)
> 09:36:58.032 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:32)
> 09:36:58.048 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:21)
> 09:36:58.064 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLoggingAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:302)
> 09:36:58.080 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLoggingAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:286)
> 09:36:58.095 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
> 09:36:58.111 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint$1.execute(EntryPoint.java:53)
> 09:36:58.127 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint$1.execute(EntryPoint.java:51)
> 09:36:58.143 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.Execution.execute(Execution.java:28)
> 09:36:58.159 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:39)
> 09:36:58.174 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
> 09:36:58.190 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:51)
> 09:36:58.206 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:33)
> 09:36:58.221 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:24)
> 09:36:58.237 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
> 09:36:58.253 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
> 09:36:58.268 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:47)

I'm guessing the pi is taking too long to complete? If anyone has any suggestions on how to make this work would like to hear.

This is using openjdk 6

Many Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37145/rosjava-build-problem-on-raspberry-pi---(gradle-build-daemon-disappeared-unexpectedly)/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2012-06-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may try disabling the Gradle daemon since that seems to be the source of the error messages. Remove rosjava_core/gradle.properties

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-07-06**:
Hi thanks for that (Soz for the late replay - been away)

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-07-06**:
Hi thanks for that (Soz for the late replay - been away)